# Setting count of UILabel in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm stuck in a strange scenario.. I'm making a cart screen, I have UITableView and every single row contains a plus button a minus button and a Label whose value would increases and decreases depending on the button user pressed. Now when I press add button of row 1 it sets incremented value of my UIlabel in every row. How to get rid of this ?

P.s. in cellForRowAtIndex path I'm setting my label's value as

```
lblCounterDisplay.text = [NSString stringwithformat:@"%d",counter];
```

whereas counter is my global value which is set as 0 by default.

EDIT:
here is my entire code

```
 // global variables
int dynamicHeight;
bool flag=NO;
int indexPathCounter = 0;
int displayValue  = 0;

  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
     [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


table.delegate = self;
table.dataSource = self;



arrForSec1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"test",@"tes",@"test",@"test",@"tes",@"test", nil];
}


// table view delegate methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;    //count of section
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [arrForSec1 count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }



    UIButton *btnplus = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 10, 23, 23)];
    [btnplus setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:btnplus];
    [btnplus addTarget:self action:@selector(testCounter:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btnplus.tag = indexPathCounter;
    btnplus.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];



    UILabel *lblCounter = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 10, 23, 23)];
    lblCounter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",displayValue];
    lblCounter.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    lblCounter.textAlignment =UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [cell addSubview:lblCounter];


    UIButton *btnMinus = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(285, 10, 23, 23)];
    [btnMinus setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:btnMinus];
    btnMinus.tag = indexPathCounter+1;
    [btnMinus addTarget:self action:@selector(testCounter:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btnMinus.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    indexPathCounter = indexPathCounter+2;


    return cell;
}


-(void)testCounter:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"kuch aya ? %ld",(long)[sender tag]);
    if([sender tag] % 2 == 0)
    {
       NSLog(@"plus!");
       displayValue = displayValue +1;

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"its minus!");
        if(displayValue != 0)
    {
        displayValue = displayValue -1;

    }


}
    [table reloadData];
}
```

Comment: what is your code for changing the text in the label and triggering the text change?

Comment: your use of indexPathCounter makes it look like you believe that every cell will get built in order. That's not the case -- your cellForRowAtIndexPath: code gets called as the user scrolls up and down. So if you are going to rely on tags in the cell, you must base them on [indexPath row] (if there's only 1 section). For example you could tag the buttons with [indexPath row] * 3, [indexPath row] * 3 + 1, [indexPath row] * 3 + 2. Then when you get a call to testCounter you can meaningfully figure out in which cell the sender lives.

Comment: can u edit my code to explain ? I'm bit of confuse at the moment

Comment: don't use tags like that. that is code smell. instead use proper cell subclasses and wire your buttons up. http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-4-uiview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counter variable should be a NSArray of counter with as many indices as row.

You would then match each row to its counter

```
 lblCounterDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [counter objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

---

EDIT:

Your global variables are the main root of your issue.

```
int indexPathCounter = 0;
int displayValue  = 0;
```

You need to track each row counts using a `NSMutableArray`.

Make the following changes:

**viewDidLoad**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    table.delegate = self;
    table.dataSource = self;

    arrForSec1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] 
                   initWithObjects:@"test",@"tes",@"test",@"test",@"tes",@"test", nil];
    //this is the array that will keep track of each count
    arrForCounters = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[arrForSec1 count]];

    for (NSString *testString in arrForSec1) {
        [arrForCounters addObject:@"0"];
    }

}
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }



    UIButton *btnplus = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 10, 23, 23)];
    [btnplus setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:btnplus];
    [btnplus addTarget:self action:@selector(increaseCounter:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btnplus.tag = indexPath.row;
    btnplus.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];



    UILabel *lblCounter = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 10, 23, 23)];
    lblCounter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", arrForCounters[indexPath.row]];
    lblCounter.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    lblCounter.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter; //UITextAlignmentCenter; (deprecated!)
    [cell addSubview:lblCounter];


    UIButton *btnMinus = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(285, 10, 23, 23)];
    [btnMinus setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:btnMinus];
    btnMinus.tag = indexPath.row + 1000;
    [btnMinus addTarget:self action:@selector(decreaseCounter:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btnMinus.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];


    return cell;
}
```

For the sake of clarity I split you testCounter Function into 2 methods:

```
-(void)increaseCounter:(id)sender
{
    int tag = [sender tag];
    int counter = [arrForCounters[tag]integerValue];

    arrForCounters[tag] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counter + 1];

    [table reloadData];
}



-(void)decreaseCounter:(id)sender
{
    int tag = [sender tag];
    int counter = [arrForCounters[tag - 1000]integerValue];


    if (counter!=0) {
        arrForCounters[tag - 1000] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counter - 1];

        [table reloadData];
    }

}
```

I created a <kbd>[SAMPLE PROJECT](https://mega.co.nz/#!7dg0mZaZ!sZIssMaLHHvzcuWnoC0t_IjA7I2fGSPg5aXV0YityUY)</kbd> for you hope it helps.

Comment: my counter value is actually coming from core data.. but okay lets suppose its an Array and in CellForRowAtIndexPath i match the above line but when user press add button how to increment in just a particle row's lblCounterDisplay?

Comment: love u Man you are brilliant (Y)